# Relationship between Cohesion and Separation

Tags: clustering, separation

[image]

Hello! May someone explain to me please how to prove the equation depiicted with the red line? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that c is the global centroid and that
[image: Formulas]

Comment: Thank you very much!